# How to build qtwayland?

Tags: linux, qt, qmake, qtwayland

I spent whole day trying to use `QtWayland.Compositor 1.0` in Qt creator. I have followed all the steps from there https://wiki.qt.io/QtWayland but I get the following error. I don't know what does it mean, that is my first contact with linux. I have the newest linux mint on a vm.

```
$ sudo make install
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/src'
cd examples/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/examples/examples.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/examples'
cd wayland/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/examples/wayland/wayland.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/examples/wayland'
Some of the required modules (qtHaveModule(waylandcompositor) qtConfig(opengl)) are not available.
Skipped.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/examples/wayland'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/emil/wayland/qtwayland/examples'
```

how can I fix that? All I want to do is to run the examples from the Qt installation :c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the content on the wiki page was written many years ago. I made an effort to clean up things I know are not relevant anymore and hope to get the wiki page in a usable state.

The problem as I see it, is that there are so many ways to build Qt, and how to build QtWayland depends on that.

The two most common options:

## Building QtWayland as part of a full (or toplevel Qt build)

When configuring Qt, you can add `-feature-wayland-server` to you configure line. And it will make sure the wayland compositor API is part of your Qt build. Configure will then fail if the dependencies of QtWayland is not met. I.e. if you need dev packages for Wayland.

Then you can either just run `make` which will build all of Qt as you configured it, or run `make module-qtwayland` which should only build QtWayland and the required dependencies (`qtbase`, `qtdeclarative`, `qtxmlpatterns`).

## Building QtWayland against an existing Qt installation (without QtWayland)

First you need to find `qmake` for your desired Qt version. If it's the one provided by the system, it's usually on your PATH already. If you are going to use Qt provided by the Qt installer, it's usually in `~/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake` or equivalent for your version and architecture.

### Clone qtwayland

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtwayland.git
cd qtwayland
git checkout v5.10.0 #or whatever version your qmake reports
```

### Configure with qmake

```
qmake
```

or

```
~/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

You should now see:

```
Qt Wayland Client ........................ yes
Qt Wayland Compositor .................... yes
```

In your terminal, or else you are probably missing some dependencies.

### Build with make

```
make
make install
```

### Build examples

Depending on your configuration, this may need to be run explicitly:

```
make sub-examples
```